# How to echo the key:value pairs of a sub array? PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm having trouble pulling out the key value pairs in only one sub array of a two dimensional array.
I'm trying to get it in the following format:

```
"Insect: b: beetle
 Insect: m: moth
 etc..."
```

here is what I've got so far:

```
$animals = array(
'insect'    =>  array('b'=>"beetle", 'm'=>"moth", 's'=>"spider"),
'mammal'    =>  array('d'=>"dolphin", 'h'=>"human", 'c'=>"chimp"),
'fish'      =>  array('a'=>"angler", 'sh'=>"shark", 'p'=>"puffer"));
echo $animals['insect']; // trying to print sub array??
echo "<pre>";
foreach($animals as $Mkey => $domains)
    foreach($domains as $key => $species)
        echo "$Mkey: $key : $species<br>"; //prints whole array
```

Comment: Sorry, did not get your question.

Comment: so basically i want to pull only the sub-array 'insect' out, and present the data as shown in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($animals['insect'] as $Mkey => $species) {
    echo "$Mkey : $species<br>";
}

// dynamic key:    
$key = 'insect';
foreach($animals[$key] as $Mkey => $species) {
    echo "$key: $Mkey : $species<br>";
}
```

Comment: how would i go about also spitting out the array name, ie. insect? to be placed infront of $Mkey, eg. "$animals['insect']: $Mkey: $species<br>"? thanks for your help :)

Comment: `echo 'insect';`?

Comment: so there's no way to echo it from the code itself? i wanted to see if it could echo out the array name and then its contents you see

Comment: `echo "Insect $Mkey : $species<br>";`?